# Is Intel Software Development Suite worth the cost?

Tags: intel, compiler-construction, parallel-processing

(this is a partial duplicate of [Are the Intel compilers worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899602/are-the-intel-compilers-worth-it))

The Intel Software Development Suite includes the C++ compiler, IPP, VTune, Thread Checker.
The Intel Parallel Studio includes the composer, the inspector and the amplifier.

Those two packages cost almost $4000, but I'll still be a student for 1 month and as such pas only $200. This is a /20 factor, but this still is $200.

I'd love to get them, even if it's only for hobby. Do you think it's worth it ? Has someone experience with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were a company I would say definitely yes, since the cost of software is much much less than the cost of people.

But since you are a student, I don't know, only you can answer this question: do you think it's worth $200? Is it something that it's just "cool" to have, or will it actually teach you new things that will help you in your professional career?

Comment: "teach you new things that will help you in your professional career?", definetely. I don't own an iPhone, if that's your question :D

Comment: I think I'll go for it after all